# Iterating over JSON put results into an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have a JSON Object from a REST API like this:

```
{
  success: true,
  message: "",
  result: [{
      Currency: "GBP",
      IsActive: true,
      BaseAddress: "1N52wHoVR79PMDishab2XmRHsbekCdGquK",
      Notice: null
    },
    {
      Currency: "USD",
      IsActive: true,
      BaseAddress: "LhyLNfBkoKshT7R8Pce6vkB9T2cP2o84hx",
      Notice: null
    },
    {
      Currency: "YEN",
      IsActive: true,
      BaseAddress: "D9GqmkGCpgtnXP7xMD78v9xfqeDkqBZBMT",
      Notice: null
    }
  ]
};
```

I just want a list of the Currency values so am iterating over it like this:

```
var data = body.result;
for (var i in data) {
  var id = data[i].Currency;
  console.log(id)
}
```

Console prints ok:

```
GDP
USD
YEN
```

But I want to put these strings into a new Array and can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas?

Comment: Haters will spit it's not JSON, but we get your point

Comment: Sorry Jeremy, I don't know what you mean, what did I do wrong? (I'm a noob trying to learn i'm afraid).

Comment: Nothing, it's just that this is not a proper, valid JSON, it's a Javascript object. And many JSON-nazis developers love to hate those who make that mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use the [`Array#Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```js
const data = {
  success: true,
  message: "",
  result: [{
      Currency: "GBP",
      IsActive: true,
      BaseAddress: "1N52wHoVR79PMDishab2XmRHsbekCdGquK",
      Notice: null
    },
    {
      Currency: "USD",
      IsActive: true,
      BaseAddress: "LhyLNfBkoKshT7R8Pce6vkB9T2cP2o84hx",
      Notice: null
    },
    {
      Currency: "YEN",
      IsActive: true,
      BaseAddress: "D9GqmkGCpgtnXP7xMD78v9xfqeDkqBZBMT",
      Notice: null
    },
    {
      Currency: "YEN",
      IsActive: true,
      BaseAddress: "D9GqmkGCpgtnXP7xMD78v9xfqeDkqBZBMT",
      Notice: null
    }
  ]
}

const currencies = [...new Set(data.result.map(a => a.Currency))];
  
console.log(currencies);
```

Comment: What if there are duplicates? Probably we don't want `["USD","USD","USD"]`.

Comment: @bitcoder.io please upvote and validate my answer if it's good for you :)

Comment: Sorry Erazihel, I don't have enough reputation to upvote but as soon as I do I'll be sure to upvote. Excellent answer!

Answer (score 0):

```js
var body = {
  success: true,
  message: "",
  result: [{
      Currency: "GBP",
      IsActive: true,
      BaseAddress: "1N52wHoVR79PMDishab2XmRHsbekCdGquK",
      Notice: null
    },
    {
      Currency: "USD",
      IsActive: true,
      BaseAddress: "LhyLNfBkoKshT7R8Pce6vkB9T2cP2o84hx",
      Notice: null
    },
    {
      Currency: "YEN",
      IsActive: true,
      BaseAddress: "D9GqmkGCpgtnXP7xMD78v9xfqeDkqBZBMT",
      Notice: null
    }
  ]
};

var res = body.result.map(item => { return item.Currency });

console.log(res);
```